# Node Red - How to stop a Bash node with button

Tags: node-red

I have a node Red Dashboard Button which starts a Bash node, Bash node executes a .sh script which lets a python file run. The python file runs in loop.

I am trying to add a button which stops the Bash node without stopping the node-red instance.

Does someone have an idea about how to do it?

Comment: I'd probably remove the `bash` tag here unless you're looking for an answer *written in* bash. (Frankly, most people who know bash won't also know Node-Red; it's a pretty small niche, which is problematic for a question where at least half the answer requires knowing details of the runtime environment).

Comment: Edit the question, which node are you using to execute the script. The `exec` node it the `daemon` node?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to record the PID of the shell script. Then you can issue a `kill` command via an exec node.

However, you may need to check whether killing the parent shell script also kills the Python script, it may not.

In reality though, it would almost certainly be better to run the Python script directly controlling any looping from within the Python script. Then you only have one executable to think about. I assume that there is probably a python library that will let you get the PID for the running script as there is in Node.js. Pass that back to Node-RED as output.